# LEFT OUTER JOIN in subquery

Tags: django, django-orm

Consider a simple `User` and `Content` models setup. I would like to get the distribution of content per user, including `0` for users without content:

```
 per_user | count
----------+-------
        0 |    89
        1 |    15
        2 |    14
```

For the sake of this question the barebone models are:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Content(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

One way to do this in pure `SQL` is:

```sql
SELECT
    per_user,
    count(per_user) count
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(c.id) per_user
      FROM app_user u
      LEFT JOIN app_content c ON (c.user_id = u.id)
     GROUP BY u.id
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY
    per_user
ORDER BY
    per_user DESC;
```

I can do this to get the `per_user` count:

```
User.objects.annotate(per_user=Count("content")).values("per_user")
```

Unfortunately I cannot stick another `.annotate(c=Count("per_user"))` at the end of this:

```
FieldError: Cannot compute Count('per_user'): 'per_user' is an aggregate
```

Comment: Is it possible to share (relevant parts of) your models. A lot of people aim to translate queries to ORM calls, but actually it is typically more effective to go the other way around: reason about models and make a query without thinking about underlying database queries.

Comment: i have added the models if it helps, but it's really barebones: every content has a user, that's all.  i guess another title of the question could be: annotating an annotation...

Comment: As I know you can't `select from subquery` but you can use SQLAlchemy together with Django ORM by using aldjemy: https://github.com/Deepwalker/aldjemy